# An estimate of the heat kernel on a bounded doain

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm interesting to PDE, and I'm asking if the heat kernel $p_{D}(t,x,y)$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions  on $[0,1]^{d}$, where $d\geq 1$ satify $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{D}p_{D}(s,x,y)dyds =c_{0} > 0$   ? for all $x\in D$.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\int_{0}^{t}\int_{D}p_{D}(s,x,y)\,dy\,ds \le  \int_{0}^{t}1\,ds =t$$
you can't have a lower bound independent of $t$. Maybe you meant a fixed $t$. But even if we replace $t$ with $\infty$, the resulting integral has no positive bound. Notice that 
$$\int_0^\infty   p_{D}(s,x,y) \,ds = g_D(x,y)$$
is Green's function for $D$. So, the question becomes: does $\int_D g_D(x,y)\,dy$ have a positive lower bound? The answer is no.  Physically speaking: $y\mapsto g_D(x,y)$ is the stationary heat distribution subject to zero boundary condition and point source at $x$. If the source $x$ is placed near the boundary, the heat goes to the boundary at once, and almost all of the domain  stays near zero temperature.

To complement the above hand-waving, I'll do the computation for $d=1$. Here $$g_D(x,y)= y(1-x) -(y-x)^+$$ 
(which is symmetric: $g_D(x,y)=g_D(y,x)$, by the way), and 
$$\int_0^1 g_D(x,y)\,dy = \frac{1-x}{2} - \frac{(1-x)^2}{2} = \frac{x(1-x)}{2}$$
As you can see, this is small near the boundary.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact I mean if does exists $c_{0} >0$ such that  $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{D}p_{D}(s,x,y)dyds \geq c_{0} t$ or  $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{D}p_{D}(s,x,y)dyds \geq c_{0} t^{\rho}$, with arbitrary $\rho >0$ ?

Comment: @user110160 No. Look at the example ($d=1$) in my answer. To find some results that are true, search for *heat content asymptotics* on the web.